# zTree !button formatting

Tags: button, formatting, rft, ztree

I want to insert a !button item. However, the layout does not look as I want. Is it possible to enlarge the button, change font size of the entered text or even arrange them side by side?

Hope somebody can help me

!button: 0 = "{\rtf \fs28 A }"; 1 = "{\rtf \fs28 B }";

This is what I am trying at the moment, but it does not work.